# Is there any simpler way to capture JPEG image from aws ec2 get-console-screenshot command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, aws-cli

I'm trying to capture AWS Instance screenshot using this command `aws ec2 get-console-screenshot --instance-id <i-0922..>`

The command gives me some json output with `InstanceId` and `ImageData` fields.

The `ImageData` field contains image in base64 encoded form as per their official documentation http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/get-console-screenshot.html

But I want the command to give image as a file, how do I achieve this?

For now I tried some hack by decoding the `ImageData` base64 contents and putting it in a file with .jpg extension, it worked!

```
cat /tmp/myimage.jpg | base64 --decode > /tmp/myimagedecode.jpg # here file /tmp/myimage.jpg contains the content of ImageData field
```

Can AWS provide some simple way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
aws ec2 get-console-screenshot --instance-id i-XXXXXXX  --query "ImageData" --output text | base64 --decode > out.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone else who comes across this and is quickly looking for the magic incantation, I think your original question had the best solution, but it can be put in one line:

```
 aws ec2 get-console-screenshot --instance-id <i-00xxxxxx> | base64 --decode > remote-capture.jpeg
```